# bootstrap - navbar tabs not rendered correclty in ie 9

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using the latest stylesheets from Twitter bootstrap 2.1.0, I can't get the navbars with tabs rendered correctly in IE explorer 9.

Image here

[image]

(sorry, I cannot embed)

It is rendered correctly in Chrome.

Here is the complete example: http://jsbin.com/usugiz/3/edit

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Strangely, it is rendered correctly in the JS Bin preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in a `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your HTML.

The top of [this](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) page will explain why if you're curious.

Comment: BRILLIANT! ... sometimes it's so simple. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I also found out it has to be the very first comment-style element in the HTML document for IE to pick it up (so no `<!-- revision ... -->` or the like in the beginning of the doc).